How can I benchmark disk throughput using dd? (writing to /dev/null is instantaneous?)
I'm trying to perform a simple disk benchmark (throughput) of my ZFS filesystem using dd.
Here is my command:
dd if=/tank/media/video/largefile.mp4 of=/dev/null bs=1M count=1000

However, it finishes instanteously:
1000+0 records out
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB, 1000 MiB) copied, 0.18307 s, 5.7 GB/s

This is obviously not actually reading the file because that speed is unrealistic.
How can I perform a read-only test for throughput?  I don't want to write the file anywhere because then I'm also testing write speed.
Also, what is a typical blocksize to use?  (for example, to simulate copying over a network using SMB or similar)

Your file is seemingly cached, thus you need to drop filesystem cache/buffers:
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Secondly using dd and writing to /dev/null are both not free CPU-time-wise, there are better tools for that. But for big enough files that shouldn't be an issue.
